# "which is people don't vote" vs "which is people not voting"

Tags: grammar

> 1. We have a big issue in my country which is people **don't vote** for elections.

The first sentence, the part that is before *which*, is okay for me cuz it contains one verb.
The second sentence contains two verbs. Is it correct or should I add -ing  like:

> 2. We have a big issue in my country which is people **not voting** for elections.

Which one sounds more native and Colloquial according to AmE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say 2. is more colloquial of the two.

To make the sentence work you need something else. Maybe something like so.

We have a big issue in my country which is that too few people vote in elections.